# Find Fragment by tag name in Container

Tags: android, fragment

I have a  relative layout and i am adding fragment in that relative layout.
Like this

```
     HomeFragment mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(mHomeFragment!=null&& mHomeFragment.isAdded()){

        fragmentTransaction.show(mHomeFragment);

    }else {

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.order_container,mHomeFragment,"Search");


    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I also have a text view where i have to display the name of fragment i added in the relative layout.
Like search in case.
How to get the name of fragment added in my relative layout suppose with 
             id = R.id.order_container

Comment: What do you mean by the "name" of the fragment?

Comment: in the above code i have added search string , as a tag in fragment . i want to retrieve that name.

Answer (score 46):

you can retrieve a Fragment by tag through

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourstringtag");
```

then you can check if your fragment is instace of `HomeFragment`

```
if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
}
```

Comment: with lowercase 'o' :) - "instanceof"

Comment: +1. But I wanna know how we can use it in nested fragments with TabLayout. I know its a stupid question but I need to know.

Answer (score 4):

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.order_container);
String tag = (String) fragment.getTag();
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the name?? You can get your fragment using the ID and doing:

```
fragment.getClass().getName();
```

is it what you want?
Or you can use:

```
fragment.getTag();
```

it's returns the tag name of the fragment, if specified.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the tag of a fragment you can use the getTag() method. This probably isn't going to be the nicest way to achieve what you are looking to do.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTag()

If you have several fragments and you will change them around, consider using an adapter.

Comment: what about if there is no fragment in container , how to check that step

Comment: You can use findFragmentById to achieve this, see answer by @JoaoBiriba it will return null if there is no fragment.

Comment: i am adding framgents dynamically what id should i give ?

Comment: It will always be the id of the container

Comment: if one fragment is already added in a container with tag "search" , then i replace first fragment with a new fragment with tag "sale" , will the id of the fragment added in container will  be same always ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findFragmentById` in `FragmentManager`

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.order_container)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I hope this will be helpful for someone.
**To find fragment by tag** we can do this:

```
String tag=getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(index).getTag();
SecondFragment f = (SecondFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container).getClass().getName();
```

Comment: Try to provide some more details in your answer