# findFragmentByTag() always return null - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application i have one main activity and several fragments. when user click the back button fragments pops one by one. I want to identify which fragment currently in the back stack. So use to identify fragments by fragment tag name. i used following code segment to get fragment tag name but it always returns null value.

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
String fragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
```

please help.

Edit,

replacing fragment with tag,

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment, text);
```

Comment: have you set TAG in Fragment ?

Comment: btw where is the line `findFragmentByTag()`??

Comment: wher should i use findFragmentByTag()

Comment: wherever you want to check the Fragment popping out from the stack.. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919006/2591002)

Comment: yes but the problem is i have several fragments and can't pass the fragment TAG name. i want to get the fragment TAG name which is in top of the fragment stack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found my mistake, it is i forgot to add TAG to back stack.

```
FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment, text);
ft.addToBackStack(text);
```

And then i can get the current fragment TAG name as follows,

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
String currentFragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `addToBackStack()` in order for this call to work. What if you want the fragment manager to _manage_ your fragments but not have it replace historically upon back. This shouldn't be the correct answer.

Comment: addToBackStack is not meant for this purpose...
Tag and addToBackStack are different things.

Comment: It shouldn't be like this, but if the fragment isn't in the backstack it won't be found  by findFragmentByTag(). "... keep in mind that the Fragment needs to be added to your FragmentManager. If you have removed() or replaced() a Fragment and haven’t added it to the backstack, you won’t be able to find it."
https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62

Answer (score 27):

You need to mention the TAG while adding/ replacing it:

```
ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment,"fragment_tag_String");
```

OR

```
ft.add(R.id.container, newFragment,"fragment_tag_String");
```

Add the fragment in BackStack as :

```
ft.addToBackStack("fragment_tag_String");
```

Then you can reuse it with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag_String");
```

Refer :

- [Replace fragment with TAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [Add fragment with TAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

## Edit :

Call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after doing the transaction

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment, text);
ft.commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

Hope it will help you ツ

Comment: i used first way to replacing fragments. but it's always return null value.

Comment: like this, FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();  ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment, text);

Comment: what is the value in text variable ? make sure it is no ""

Comment: where should i use getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag_String"); Now i'm using above way to get tag name. (FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
String fragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName())

Comment: Are you able to fetch TAG in `fragmentTag`?

Comment: yes all TAGS are submitting. the problem is can't get those back when clicking the back button.

Comment: *findFragmentByTag()* is used to get Fragment with the help of TAG.. your requirement is something else  *i want to get the fragment TAG name which is in top of the fragment stack.*