# findFragmentByTag return null fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this really simple code :

```
    InboxFragment ibf = new InboxFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ibf, InboxFragment.TAG);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();

    InboxFragment ib2 = (InboxFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(InboxFragment.TAG);
```

I don't understand why my `ib2` is null.

What is the best way to manage different fragments in my activity ? Because I must implement a "Template" system, and each template is represents by a fragment. I have to switch between templates.

- Declare all my fragments in a first time and call the good one when the template changes. (Take memory for nothing if the template doesn't change)
- Add the fragment when the template changes. (When i destroy the fragment, how can I recall it, where the instance is store).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988588/findfragmentbytag-always-return-null-android). Add your tag to backstack getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(InboxFragment.TAG);

Comment: Why didn't you call `commit` ?

Comment: Same effect if i call `commit()` after 'add()'

Comment: Tried calling `executePending`?

Answer (score 2):

[See here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions())

> After a `FragmentTransaction` is committed with `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, it is scheduled to be executed asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this function (only from the main thread) to do so.

So add this

`.executePendingTransactions()` after committing to do such operations.

Comment: Same result with `.executePendingTransactions()`

Comment: be sure it is called after committing, and `fragmentTransaction.commit();` and `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` be sure of it as well. Try not chaining them. Split them.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` a new `FragmentTransaction` instance is created.

You never commit the first transaction:

> getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ibf, InboxFragment.TAG);

but only the second (empty) one:

> getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();

Write the following line instead:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ibf, InboxFragment.TAG).commit();
```

In addition to that, the `FragmentManager` will return null if you call `findFragmentByTag()` immediately after adding the `Fragment`, because adding a `Fragment` will be executed asynchronously by default. You can add the following statement to force execution (but it may result in bad performance):

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

In your code, you would achieve the same result (initialising ib2) by just writing

```
ib2 = ibf;
```

About your "template system": I think it's a good practice to only create what is necessary. Once objects are created, it may be a good idea to keep them around (depends on the app). [Retained Fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) may be helpful in your case, but it is recommended to use them mostly for storing data, less for keeping a hold on UI elements.