# How to add fragment Tag in a FragmentPagerAdapter to reference the fragment later?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I tried the following but it didn't help . How can I set tags or acess tags of fragments from FragmentPagerAdapter ?

```
        @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)mcontext;

    if (position == 0) {
       Fragment discoverFragment =  new DiscoverFragment();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(discoverFragment, "discover").commit();
        return discoverFragment;
    } else if (position == 1){
        Fragment myFeedFragment =  new MyFeedFragment();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(myFeedFragment, "myfeed").commit();
        return myFeedFragment;
    } else {
        Fragment filterFragment =  new FilterFragment();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(filterFragment, "filter").commit();
        return filterFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: findFragmentByTag function can be used [This will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918854/find-fragment-by-tag-name-in-container)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are setting the tags correctly. Anyway, this way should work.

Set tag:

```
MyFeedFragment myFeedFragment= new MyFeedFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFeedFragment, "myfeed");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And then you can get it by searching tag:

```
    List fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

    Fragment discoverFrag = null;
    Fragment myFeedFragment = null;
    Fragment filterFragment = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i++) {
        if (((Fragment) fragments.get(i)).getTag() == "discover")
            discoverFrag = (Fragment) fragments.get(i);

        if (((Fragment) fragments.get(i)).getTag() == "myfeed")
            myFeedFragment = (Fragment) fragments.get(i);

        if (((Fragment) fragments.get(i)).getTag() == "filter")
            filterFragment = (Fragment) fragments.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this as error when I used my code 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Then try this above.

Comment: tried your method. Got error 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment DiscoverFragment{1488c4bd id=0x7f0d00a8 myfeed}: was myfeed now android:switcher:2131558536:0

Comment: You need to be more specific. Post your full stacktrace, and line of code where crash happens. Also, post code of adapter and fragment/activity where you want to get refernce

Answer (score 0):

Use this this class as your adapter

```
class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        private String mPagetile[];

        public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            mPagetile = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageTitle);
            mFragmentManager = fm;
            mFragmentTags = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new "Your_fragment";
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
                Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
                String tag = f.getTag();
                mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
            String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
            if (tag == null)
                return null;
            return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mPagetile[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return "Number of fragments";
        }
    }
```

Now with the instance of SwipeAdapter call getFrament(int "position of fragment"); 
Hope you get it.

Comment: gettag() method gives null. We should set Tag values in fragmentpagerAdapter ?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a fragment used in your FragmentPagerAdapter, you can do this anywhere (Kotlin) :

```
for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
    if (fragment is YourFragment) {
        val yourFragment = fragment as YourFragment
    }
}
```