# findFragmentByTag returns null on all fragments except one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there are some questions that cover this issue, but mines kind of different because it doesn't use `fragment` transition (I don't know how it works so I didnt use it).

What my `MainActivity` does is, it adds `fragments` on the `tabBar` and creates functions to pass in a message data from one `fragment` to another `fragment`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InputTab.SendMessage, FollowingTab.SendMessage, FollowerTab.SendMessage, ProfileTab.SendMessage, UserSearchResultTab.SendMessage {

    private SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static String currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProfileTab());

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        pageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Sets up the ViewPager with the sections adapter

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((viewPager));

    }

    // Adds fragments to SectionsPageAdapter and gives names for the corresponding tab

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new InputTab(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileTab(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new GithubTab(), "Github Repos");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowerTab(), "Followers");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowingTab(), "Followings");
        adapter.addFragment(new UserSearchResultTab(), "test");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToProfile(String message) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.container + ":" + 1;
        ProfileTab profile = (ProfileTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        profile.displayReceivedData(message);
    }

    @Override
   public void sendDataToFollowers(String message) {
       String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.container + ":" + 3;
       FollowerTab follower = (FollowerTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
       follower.displayReceivedData(message);
   }
```

The data successfully passes in to the `profileTab`, but when I debug it, it gives me `null` for other tabs like

```
FollowerTab follower = (FollowerTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

This one. Thus, it gives me a crash whenever I try to send a data to `FollowerTab`.

What am I missing and how can I make it to become a non-null `fragment`?

Comment: A bit late but. Are you using `SectionsPageAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of fragment transaction you need to put a tag to your fragment. you have not set any tag to your fragment. this is the reason you get null. 
 you need to put tag in your fragment like.

```
FragmentA fragment=new FragmentA();
 getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,"tag").commit();
```

here tag return a tag at the time you use findFragmentByTag(tag);

Comment: Sorry where do I have to add this? In the OnCreate or inside setupViewPager or the sendData?

Comment: @Dawn17 , you you want to perform some action on the click of tab then you can use the tab click listener or inside onclick method you can write your code that may help you. Or you can check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132964/how-to-add-fragment-tag-in-a-fragmentpageradapter-to-reference-the-fragment-late] that may help you