# parentActivityName to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest

Today's question is to get back from an activity to a specific fragment.
I want to do this as ParentActivityName does, with a onbackpressed arrow in toolbar.
I think about something like recall the activity that contained fragment, but when it restored it doesn't show the right fragment. Have any idea ?

```
    <activity
        android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity"
        android:name=".Register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"/>
```

Comment: talk is cheap, show the code!

Comment: i didnot understand. how many activities do you have? use tags and add fragments to backstack + findFragmentByTag("yourstringtag");  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918854/find-fragment-by-tag-name-in-container

Comment: I do edit the question is that better ?